# Redirecting output to multiple files and to stdout simultaneously in win XP command line

Tags: windows, command-line, redirect, stream, cmd

I would like to redirect the output from a command to a file and to stdout. I am using Windows XP command line.

I realize that there is a command in linux called tee which will do this, but I want this in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [tee for windows](http://www.google.com/search?q=tee+for+windows).

Comment: Posting a link to Google isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The first hit when googling [windows tee](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+tee) gives [UNIX-style tee utility for Windows](http://www.chipstips.com/?p=129)

Answer (score 2):

The simple DOS shell doesn't have the ability to do this simultaneously.
Try using:

[Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx)

or

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If using `tee` (one of the various Windows variants) isn't an option and the command isn't long-running or you don't need to do further processing of the output in real time, then

```
command > file && type file
```

would do that for you. But only under the mentioned circumstances. You're probably be better off using `tee`.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has `tee-object` (standard alias `tee`) if you are using a decent shell.