# Using DOS/CMD/batch files how can you show Console output, and redirect the STDOUT and STDERR streams to files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, stream, dos

direct console to ok.log, and errors to error.log for example

Comment: call C:\local\jboss.bat  > %CTODAY%.jboss.log 2> %CTODAY%.err.jboss.log

only writes to jboss.log and not err.jboss.log =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[your command] > ok.log 2> error.log
```

Comment: I tried that, it just writes to file and doesnt show any output

Comment: amvx - are you sure you are writing to stdout and stderr, and are you sure that your %CTODAY% is valid?  'cause if I do it with Python, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I have found to do this is by using some variant of the [UNIX `tee` command](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/tee.html).  You would use it like:

```
[your command] 2> error.log | tee ok.log
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, if your goal is to split output into both stdout and a file, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666815/redirecting-output-to-multiple-files-and-to-stdout-simultaneously-in-win-xp-comma).